# Can't mount external laptop HDD on laptop

Tags: laptop, external-hdd, 32-bit

I'm running a vanilla instance of 32bit Ubuntu 11.04 installed on the [k53e](http://www.asus.com/Notebooks/Versatile_Performance/K53E/) laptop.  The machine is up to date.  I have an external laptop HDD that I'm accessing via the [rocketfish RF-HD3025](http://www.bestbuy.com/site/Rocketfish™+-+2.5%22+Serial+ATA+Hard+Drive+Enclosure/1600065.p?id=1218273487047&skuId=1600065).  The drive is not found with fdisk -l or gparted.  I see the following with dmesg:

```
[ 2108.679866] usb 2-1.2: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 8
[ 2108.828091] scsi11 : uas
[ 2111.200568] scsi 11:0:0:0: Direct-Access     SYMWAVE  TOSHIBA MK1637GS 2C   PQ: 0 ANSI: 4
[ 2118.194699] scsi 11:0:0:0: uas_eh_abort_handler tag 0
[ 2118.194713] scsi 11:0:0:0: uas_eh_device_reset_handler tag 0
[ 2118.194721] scsi 11:0:0:0: uas_eh_target_reset_handler tag 0
[ 2118.194727] scsi 11:0:0:0: uas_eh_bus_reset_handler tag 0
[ 2118.266857] usb 2-1.2: reset high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 8
[ 2118.408428] scsi 11:0:0:0: Device offlined - not ready after error recovery
[ 2118.408507] scsi 11:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
[ 2118.408528] scsi 11:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
[ 2118.410213] scsi 11:0:0:1: Enclosure         SYMWAVE  SES              2C   PQ: 0 ANSI: 4
[ 2118.410448] scsi 11:0:0:2: uas_sense_old: urb length 26 disagrees with IU sense data length 510, using 18 bytes of sense data
[ 2118.411282] sd 11:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[ 2118.411512] ses 11:0:0:1: Attached Enclosure device
[ 2118.411673] ses 11:0:0:1: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 13
```

I loaded Ubuntu 10.10 via flashdisk and it mounts the drives fine.  I can also access the disk via Windows 7.  Seems to be just Ubuntu 11 at the moment.  Any ideas on what I can do to get it mounted?  I'm relatively new to troubleshooting Ubuntu issues.

UPDATE: I can see the device now via lsusb.  Here are the details.

```
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 1ca1:18a9  
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.10
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x1ca1 
  idProduct          0x18a9 
  bcdDevice           43.07
  iManufacturer           1 
  iProduct                2 
  iSerial                 3 
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           85
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0x80
      (Bus Powered)
    MaxPower              500mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass         8 Mass Storage
      bInterfaceSubClass      6 SCSI
      bInterfaceProtocol     80 Bulk (Zip)
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x84  EP 4 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x03  EP 3 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       1
      bNumEndpoints           4
      bInterfaceClass         8 Mass Storage
      bInterfaceSubClass      6 SCSI
      bInterfaceProtocol     98 
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x01  EP 1 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
        INTERFACE CLASS:  04 24 01 00
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x83  EP 3 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
        INTERFACE CLASS:  04 24 02 00
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x84  EP 4 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
        INTERFACE CLASS:  04 24 03 00
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x05  EP 5 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
        INTERFACE CLASS:  04 24 04 00
```

UPDATE #2

If I wait for a minute, I get these additional lines with dmesg:

```
[ 3184.660662] sd 11:0:0:0: uas_eh_abort_handler tag 0
[ 3184.660679] sd 11:0:0:0: uas_eh_device_reset_handler tag 0
[ 3184.660687] sd 11:0:0:0: uas_eh_target_reset_handler tag 0
[ 3184.660699] sd 11:0:0:0: uas_eh_bus_reset_handler tag 0
[ 3184.732711] usb 2-1.2: reset high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 7
[ 3184.874194] sd 11:0:0:0: Device offlined - not ready after error recovery
[ 3184.874267] sd 11:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
[ 3184.874290] sd 11:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
[ 3184.874301] sd 11:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
[ 3184.874309] sd 11:0:0:0: [sdb] READ CAPACITY failed
[ 3184.874313] sd 11:0:0:0: [sdb]  Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[ 3184.874321] sd 11:0:0:0: [sdb] Sense not available.
[ 3184.874330] sd 11:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
[ 3184.874338] sd 11:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[ 3184.874344] sd 11:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 00 00 00 00
[ 3184.874351] sd 11:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
[ 3184.874358] sd 11:0:0:0: [sdb] Asking for cache data failed
[ 3184.874363] sd 11:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[ 3184.874863] sd 11:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
```

UPDATE #3

I gave up on trying to get this working.  I loaded up Ubuntu 10.10 so I could get all the files.  While there, I recorded what dmesg said when the drive successfully loaded.  Hope this helps someone.

```
[  142.777698] usb 2-1.2: USB disconnect, address 3
[  151.417332] usb 2-1.2: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 5
[  151.561647] scsi8 : usb-storage 2-1.2:1.0
[  153.928689] scsi 8:0:0:0: Direct-Access     SYMWAVE  TOSHIBA MK1637GS 2C   PQ: 0 ANSI: 4
[  153.929984] sd 8:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
[  153.930523] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdc] 312576000 512-byte logical blocks: (160 GB/149 GiB)
[  153.931639] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off
[  153.931653] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 67 00 10 08
[  153.931660] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  153.935251] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  153.935263]  sdc: sdc1 sdc2 < sdc5 sdc6 sdc7 sdc8 >
[  154.017342] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  154.017353] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI disk
[  155.238996] EXT4-fs (sdc7): recovery complete
[  155.239455] EXT4-fs (sdc7): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suggested solution:

Try not permitting *umount* to call smart test for this disc.

- copy the file `80-udisks.rules` from the directory `/lib/udev/rules.d` to the directory `/etc/udev/rules.d`

i.e.

```
sudo cp /lib/udev/rules.d/80-udisks.rules /etc/udev/rules.d
```

- Comment out the following lines in the file `/etc/udev/rules.d/80-udisks.rules` that is put a **#** at the start of the line so that it reads as shown

i.e.

```
sudo nano /etc/udev/rules.d/80-udisks.rules
```

location in the file:

```
# USB ATA enclosures with a SAT layer
#KERNEL=="sd*[!0-9]", ATTR{removable}=="0", ENV{ID_BUS}=="usb", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="disk", IMPORT{program}="udisks-probe-ata-smart $tempnode"

# ATA disks driven by libata
#KERNEL=="sd*[!0-9]", ATTR{removable}=="0", ENV{ID_BUS}=="ata", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="disk", IMPORT{program}="udisks-probe-ata-smart $tempnode"

# ATA disks connected via SAS (not driven by libata)
#KERNEL=="sd*[!0-9]", ATTR{removable}=="0", ENV{ID_BUS}=="scsi", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="disk", ENV{ID_VENDOR}=="ATA", IMPORT{program}="udisks-probe-ata-smart $tempnode"
```

The rules in the directory `/etc/udev/rules.d` override the `/lib/udev/rules.d` rules. It is recommended not to edit anything in `/lib/udev/rules.d` and to put personal rules into `/etc/udev/rules.d`

[source post#6](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1782546)

Comment: Excellent walkthrough of the solution and great answer but unfortunately it didn't make any progress.  The drive isn't detected and I'm finding lsusb and fdisk still can't "see" anything.  I did a hard boot in case there was some loading magic but that didn't help either.

Comment: Nick - if you cant see with `lsusb` then have a look in your bios - do you have some usb options such as "legacy usb support"?  Try toggling these on or off.

Comment: I'll take a look as soon as I get home.  Since I can access the drives from Windows (dual boot) and Ubuntu 10.10, would that make any difference?  Thanks again for your continued help!

Comment: linux is much more "sensitive" to this sort of thing - windows lets you get away with almost anything!

Comment: I apologize, I looked too quick.  There is a new entry in the lsusb that I hadn't seen before.  I'm not sure when it started showing up but it's there now.  Will update the question with details...

Comment: Nick - is the first dmesg trace still valid?  It might be worth booting without the external HDD plugged in.  Just before plugging in the HDD type `dmesg`.  Note the [ time ] in the trace - plug in the HDD and rerun `dmesg` the new output from [ time ] is directly related to your HDD.  Also - can you confirm that this is not USB port specific.  I've known some USB ports not to work with some External HDDs - espcially those USB ports on an external/internal USB hub.

Comment: The dmesg is still valid but I found that if I waited for another minute, more messages appeared.  Updated the question with the additional trace.  I issued a dmesg -c prior to plugging in the HDD to make sure that I was definitely getting those messages.  I tried all the USB ports and they all behave the same, reporting the USB device but not mounting it.  Thanks again for the help!

Comment: @Nick - your last trace looks interesting - it is mounting on SDC whereas in Natty it is mounting as SDB.  Have you got another HDD connected (external/internal)?  Maybe disconnecting that drive will help.  Also it is mounting sdc7 - what partitioning have you got on that drive?