# Hard drive not mounting

Tags: mount, hard-drive, external-hdd, samsung

I'm trying to connect to an external HD (Samsun D3 station).

- It is not recognize by any OS (MAC, windows and linux).
- I have tried with different cable (USB and AC) and no difference
- I even try open up the box and plunging directly

It seems to install the driver and "spin" the disk for roughly 10 secondes before disconnecting and being un-detectable...

Here is output of `dmesg`:

```
[42377.183923] usb 2-6: new SuperSpeed USB device number 11 using xhci_hcd
[42377.201479] usb 2-6: New USB device found, idVendor=04e8, idProduct=6123
[42377.201483] usb 2-6: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[42377.201485] usb 2-6: Product: D3 Station
[42377.201486] usb 2-6: Manufacturer: Samsung 
[42377.201488] usb 2-6: SerialNumber: 00000000011E0A49
[42377.202386] usb-storage 2-6:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[42377.202464] scsi host8: usb-storage 2-6:1.0
[42378.202328] scsi 8:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Samsung  D3 Station       0202 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[42378.202560] sd 8:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[42378.203368] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] Spinning up disk...
[42383.663679] .....................
[42404.588868] usb 2-6: USB disconnect, device number 11
[42404.772994] .ready
[42404.773145] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[42404.773147] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] Sense not available.
[42404.773188] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[42404.773200] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 4c 00 00 40
[42404.773226] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[42404.773228] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[42404.773426] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[42404.773429] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] Sense not available.
[42404
.773443] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
```

Any idea what it means ? And what to do ?
Many thanks in advance,

Comment: Not a duplicate, but a similar question with one suggested solution: http://askubuntu.com/questions/61010/cant-mount-external-laptop-hdd-on-laptop

Comment: @Jos, this is similar but still not the same problem. I cannot connect on any OS... It seems to be more an hardware problem as the disconnection is not explained...

Answer (score 0):

I went to a professional agency, which gave me the following diagnostic:

> "It appear that the firmware defective (on the electronic card and plate of the disk. Furthermore, it seems that the data are crypted via an interface SATA/USB."

or in french

> " Seagate Z1E7SPVR. Problème détecté : firmware défectueux (sur la carte électronique et plateaux du disque dur). De plus il est fort possible qu'un cryptage des données soient effectués par la carte d'interface SATA/USB. Il est possible que des défauts physiques soient détectés ultérieurement, une fois le problème de firmware réglé."

I'll keep the post update if I found a way to solve it. But at least I kown what's wrong. Any idea how to do that myself without paying 2600.- CHF ?